# Do facebook custom actions inheriting from 'like' show up in the the 'like' table on FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've created a custom object and a custom action that can be performed on the object that inherits from Like on Facebook.  I've asked the users of the site to provide me with the "read stream" permission.  Can I query the object_id on the like table in FQL to get a list of user_ids?

I would like to do a query from FQL such as:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="OBJECT_ID_OF_MY_CUSTOM_OBJECT"
```

Comment: The object_id will refer to a post made by your users using your app, like UserA did CUSTOM-ACTION on OBJECT, and if that post has likes then you can get them using the fql like table.